# Absolute Coordinates on a landscape 600x1024 screen

Tags: display, resolution, coordinates

[image]

Shown above is the issue I am facing. I have a screen that is 7" Screen Landscape. It should be 1024x600 yet when I use evtest I find that its actually 600x1024 but landscape. I have no idea how I would map this out within Figma and get the coordinates for anything on the screen. Any ideas?

Prerequisites

I can't use evtest to get the button coordinates on each screen. I need to map out the true coordinates in a program, or on paper.

I can't import or load any modules or modify the system in any way.

Comment: No this is not. This is a personal project. I have attempted to use x/600*1024, y/1024*600 but that doesn't line up with what I am seeing on screen

Comment: Or does anyone know if its possible to recreate something like this with a program? I was thinking Android Studio but I dont know if it has the capability to recreate this exact screen.